# Displaced texture paint

Tags: texture-painting

I am trying to paint a texture in blender using Texture Paint. The problem I have is that when I try to paint on the model the draw is painted in a different position from the area where I painted.
I'm attaching a picture for you to see what I mean.

[image: You can see the place where I am brushing the pain and the area where it is being actually colored.]

You can see the place where I am brushing the pain and the area where it is being actually colored.